# Immutable database to huge write volume

Tags: database, cqrs, microservices, event-sourcing, datomic

I'm building a application that need to be created using an immutable database, I know about Datomic, but's not [recommended](http://www.datomic.com/faq.html) to huge data volume (my application will have thousands, or more, writes per second).

I already did some search about it and I could't find any similar database that do not have this "issue".

My application will use event sourcing and microservices pattern.

Any suggestions about what database should I use?

Answer (score 3):

Greg Young's [Event Store](https://geteventstore.com/) appears to fit your criteria.

- Stores your data as a series of immutable events over time.
- Claims to be benchmarked at 15,000 writes per second and 50,000 reads per second.

Comment: These benchmarks are relative to the hardware used. It can be much more that 5K writes if you use fast disks.

Answer (score 2):

[Amazon's DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) can scale to meet very high TPS demands. It can certainly handle 10 to 100 of thousands of writes per second sustained if your schema is designed properly but it is not cheap.

Your question is a bit vague about whether you need to be able to sustain tens of thousands of writes per second, or you need to be able to burst to tens of thousands of writes. It's also not clear how you intend to read the data.

How big is a typical event/record?

Could you batch the writes?

Could you partition your writes?

Have you looked into something like [Amazon's Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/)? With small events you could have a relatively cheap ingestion pipeline and then perhaps use S3 for long term storage. It would certainly be cheaper than DynamoDB.

Azure offers similar services as well but I'm not as familiar with their offerings.